# Clipping sound in looping audiostream

Tags: java, loops, audio, audio-streaming, audiotrack

I am having trouble playing a continuous sine wave with AudioTrack, it works, but I get a clipping sound, basically there is a short break in the audio stream when its looping. I assume there is something easy to be done here, but I don't know what it is. I have tried changing the loopLength, but it only changes the interval for the clipping.

Here is my code:

```
public void playSound() {

    AudioTrack mAudioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 44100,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
            256, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

    int loopLength = 2 * this.mSampleRate;

    while (isPlaying) {
        double[] mSound = new double[loopLength];

        for (int i = 0; i < loopLength; i = i + 1) {
            mSound[i] = Math.sin((1.0 * Math.PI * i / (this.mSampleRate / pitch)));
            mBuffer[i] = (short) (mSound[i] * Short.MAX_VALUE);
        }

        mAudioTrack.play();
        mAudioTrack.write(mBuffer, 0, loopLength);

    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you extend the buffer to hold 10 sine waves, does the clipping sound happen 1/10th as often? Based on that you should be able to tell if it's an issue with the data you're writing to the buffer, or an issue with repeating the buffer

Comment: Well I have the loopLength to 2*sampleRate, which would basically mean that the loop is 2 seconds right? And as long as I am having int numbers on the frequency, the loop will always be an exact number of sine waves, right? Or I am thinking wrongly here?

Comment: Actually it works for some frequencies but not all.. Especially it doesn't work whenI try to have different frequencies played in right and left ear.. The loop above modified as follows:
       mSound[i] = Math.sin((1.0 * Math.PI * i / (this.mSampleRate / pitch)));
       mSound[i+1] = Math.sin((1.0 * Math.PI * i / (this.mSampleRate / pitch+beat)));
  
I now hear the clipping sound only in on of the ears, the one that generates the tone (pitch + beat). Both pitch and beat are always integers.

Comment: Actually, as long as both beat and pitch are even numbers it works, but if any is an odd number its clipping..

Comment: Can you post a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Suddenly it works, can't really say that I did anything else then before, but the clipping is gone anyway :)

Comment: However I have a new problem, it seems that for frequencies above around 4 - 5 K Hz, there is a second tone generated with lower frequency, its not for all frequencies but for quite many I can definetly hear a second tone.. What can this be? Some kind of resonance? I have tried increasing sampling rate but its not changing anything, and using 44100 should be enough up to around 20 K Hz if I understand correctly?